# definition about $\{ f = -\infty \}$

Tags: real-analysis

> [image]

Can someone tell me why I can't define

$\{ f = -\infty \}$ as $\cup_{n \geq 1} \{ f <-n \}$?

I know I will miss all the $f > -n$, but don't we just care about touching $-\infty$?

Also, why we take the closure for the second one but not the first?

Comment: At most, as $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\{f<-n\}$. And, in fact, $X\setminus \bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N} \{f>-n\}=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\{f\le-n\}$.

Comment: Yeah but $\{f < -2 \} \subset \{f <-1\}$?

Answer (score 2):

It's not the closure they are taking, but the complement.

The set $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N} \{ f < -n\}$ is the set of $x$ such that, *for some $n$*, we have $f(x) < -n$. What you want is that $f(x)< -n$ *for every $n$*, so the correct definition is $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N} \{ f < -n\}$, or, what is the same, the complement of $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N} \{ f \geqslant  -n\}$.

Answer (score 1):

First, as you have already been told, you should have written $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\{f<-n\}$.

Besides, $\mathcal C$ denotes complement, not closure.

Comment: But won't I get a decending chain of $\dots \subset \{f<-2\} \subset \{ f < -1 \} $?

Comment: Yes, you will. And... ?

Comment: Wouldn't the intersection be just $\{f < -1 \}$? Sorry if this sounds crazy

Comment: @Hawk No, it wouldn't and, yes, it sounds crazy.

Comment: AH nvm, the intersection is the smallest set, it can't be the $\{ f < -1 \}$.

Comment: @Hawk Quite rIght!